# VBA SERIAL NUMBER

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

If TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text = "" Then
Unload Me
UserForm1.Show
Else

.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm")

End If
End With
End Sub
```

PLEASE CHECK THIS EXCEL SHEET:
[image]

While I am entering data to userform I need serial number for my each entry.

Image description of entries

[image]

I use this code for my commandbutton1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        If TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            Unload Me
            UserForm1.Show
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I use this code for my commandbutton1                                            Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

If TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text = "" Then
Unload Me
UserForm1.Show
Else

.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm")

End If
End With
End Sub

Comment: update your question with that informaion and you'll get a better response

Answer (score 1):

In Excel Date & Time is stored in the form of serial number.

```
dim id as double
id = Int(CDbl(Now) * 100000)
```

increase 0s in 100000 if you need more precise ID.

Comment: UNABLE TO SOLVE

Comment: did you get duplicate numbers?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no serial no. or unique# stored in vba.

What you can do is have a named range and within that the first column would be Serial#. Insert a dummy value of "1" to the first row of this named range.

Now when you open the form, pull this number+1. and when the user hits the button save it to the named range.

Next time he opens the form, load the last row of the range which will have serial# 2.